# Create matrix from patches of numbers in a vector

Tags: matlab

Say I have an input row vector, consisting of 0s and of patches of numbers without any indication on their range:

```
  A = [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 22 22 22 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 0 1 1];
```

I would like to create a `2 x m` matrix, where `m` is the amount of patches, where the first row of  column `j` keeps track of the values in the `jth` patch, and where the second row of column `j` keeps track of the average index of the `jth` patch (say the index will be the first integer to the left of the average if it is not integer).

The output associated to my example shoud be:

```
out =

 1    22     6     1
 4    12    18    22
```

I'm trying to work it out with `find`, it might end up working but it is ugly as hell and will probably be very slow, plus I'm pretty sure one of you has a cool trick in his sleeve!

I got something working (see code below), but it will not work if the patches are not distinct (i.e. if `A` contains patches that are not separated with at least one `0`):

```
d1 = diff([0 A]);

idx_S = find(d1>0);

idx_E = find(d1<0)-1;

if length(idx_E)<length(idx_S)

    idx_E = [idx_E length(A)];

end

idx_M = floor(mean([idx_E;idx_S],1));

out = [A(idx_M);idx_M];
```

For example, for:

```
A = [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 22 22 22 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 1 1];
```

it will output

```
out =

     1    22     6
     4    12    18
```

instead of

```
out =

 1    22     6     1
 4    12    18    21
```

Comment: So you're trying to do run-length encoding on the nonzero elements of the array?

Comment: Well if it means that, sure!

Comment: Except I don't want to grab the lengths of the patches, but the average indexes of the patches

Comment: It's not *exactly* what you want, but as a search term it should give you some ideas.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused by the whole distinct patches thing.

Comment: Is it better now @beaker?

Comment: Okay, that's logical. If you look for implementations of RLE, you should find something that will give you (at least) the first index of each group of distinct values. I don't have time to work on an answer right now, but I'm sure you'll find something useful. BTW, this is the opposite of what `repelem()` does, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comments from beaker, some quick search about run-length encoding led me [there](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/%7Emarios/matlab/mtt.pdf), which applied to my problem gives:

```
A = [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 22 22 22 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 1 1];

idx_E = [find(A(1:end-1) ~= A(2:end)) length(A)]; % end of patches, keeping patches of zeros

idx_S = [1 idx_E(1:(end-1))+1]; % start of patches, idem

idx_M = floor(mean([idx_E;idx_S],1)); % mean index, idem

out = [A(idx_M);idx_M];

out(:,A(idx_M)==0) = []; % removing patches of zeros

% out =
%    1    22     6     1
%    4    12    18    21
```

Comment: I think this is about 10x faster than mine, but even for large inputs (`numel(A)=25,000`) in my testing both complete in under 0.05sec which makes performance likely irrelevant. Nice application of RLE though.

Answer (score 1):

One solution:

```
% Your input:
A = [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 22 22 22 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 0 1 1];

% Detect the variation
ind = find(diff([0,A,0]>0));

% Construct the output array
res = [A(ind(1:2:end-1)); floor(mean(reshape(ind,2,[]))-0.5)]
```

And we got

```
% res =  
%     1   22    6    1
%     4   12   18   22
```

Notice that this method will fail if two patchs are not separate by a least one 0.

Comment: I might need it to work with non distinct patches as well, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yeah, I've writed my answer before your edit.

Comment: Note this gives different results to the other two answers because of your note about not handling patches without a 0 splitter, which the OP has since edited in as a requirement to the question

Answer (score 1):

This solution seems a little dense, but does achieve what you want, for "patches" of numbers regardless whether they are split by a zero or not.

```
A = [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 22 22 22 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 1 1];
m = arrayfun( @(x) x-1+floor(find([A(x:end),NaN]~=A(x),1)/2), find([1,diff(A)].*A) );
m = [A(m); m];

% m = 
%  1    22     6     1
%  4    12    18    21
```

To break this down:

- `[0,diff(A)]` Find the point-to-point deltas between elements (patches start/end when non-zero).
- `find([0,diff(A)].*A)` Convert from array the same size as `A` to the indicies of the non-zero elements (filtered by multiplying by `A`, removed when `A=0`).
- `arrayfun( ___, find([0,diff(A)].*A) )` Loop over these indicies
- `@(x) x-1+floor(find([A(x:end),NaN]~=A(x),1)/2)` For each element `x` of the index array, return the "middle" of the patch which is defined as the range between `x` and the next element not equal to `A(x)`.

Then finally `m` is defined as these indicies concatenated with the values of `A` at those indicies.